# Delphi. Подключение модулей после компиляции программы (моды)

Tags: delphi, модули, mod

Я делаю игру и думаю как добавить в нее моды. Может можно как-то после компиляции считывать список модов и загружать их как модули типа uses? Как вообще в играх делают моды?

Comment: Уточните версию Дельфи и целевую ОС. Если для Windows, то можно использовать dll или bpl-файлы. Или вы можете использовать какой то интерпритируемый язык и загружать файлы, написанные на нем, в свой внутренний интерпретатор. Или вам достаточно будет просто файлов конфигурации в том формате, который вы придумаете.

Comment: Delphi 10.3 (последний). ОС - Windows. Можно про dll и bpl подробнее?

Comment: Изучайте: [Разработка системы плагинов в Delphi](https://www.gunsmoker.ru/2011/12/delphi.html)

Comment: Хотел дать ссылку на статью в королевстве дельфи, а оно закрылось. :-( Дожили, блин.

Comment: @Eugene [Как закрылось?](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/search.asp)

Comment: @Mbo фух, ложная тревога. ru закрылся, com остался, собака гугл отправил на ru. Вот статья http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=512 . Кстати, советую вопросы по дельфи задавать на королевстве http://www.delphikingdom.com/table/add.asp нежели чем на ресурсах, таких как этот.

Comment: @Eugene Увы, жизнь на форумах чуть теплится.

Comment: @MBo, на королевстве есть ответы на свежие вопросы, я посмотрел.

Comment: @Mr Lucky Tomas комментарии к статье на королевстве тоже посмотрите.

Comment: @Eugene, ruSO тоже неплохой сайт для дельфистов, зря Вы так ;) По уму, следует использовать все доступные толковые ресурсы (форумы, сайты) для решения проблемы и поиска информации. Кстати, недавно обнаружил, что форум "Мастера Дельфи" таки закрылся((

Comment: @Dima Про DM Керк предупреждал, что сайт будет какое-то время отключен, пока(если) утрясут проблемы со владельцем/регистрацией

Comment: @Dima, нет, на SO мыслящим людям делать нечего, соответственно здесь их мало. А уж по Дельфи совсем мало. Я видел как отвечают php-ки и несут чушь и этот ответ получает много голосов и выбирается как верный. Сами принципы построения ресурсы не те.